# Is iOS OpenSource? And Mac OS X/Darwin?

Tags: macos, open-source, ios

I notice on the open opensource.apple.com site. It has iOS. Is it opensource?

If it is, How do i build it. I would love to have a self built iOS :P. 
And, mac. Is that 100% open source? I know there is a duplicate question to that one but, Is it actually possible to build it was what i was getting at.

I see there are more packages than iOS so i imagine that its more possible for the OS X than iOS. So, does anyone know the answer to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS and OS X are not open source.  They both incorporate some open source components; in particular, both are based on the open source Darwin kernel.  The UI is proprietary, however.

Comment: Okay, thanks! But is it possible to build with what is there on the site or is there no UI on the site at all?

Comment: You can't build much of anything with what's there.  Not even the base Darwin OS is usable as is; [PureDarwin](http://www.puredarwin.org) is the latest usable OS distribution based on it.  And while there may be some UI components around, neither Display PDF nor Core Graphics are there.